# Pass multiple select array of items from Angular 2 to Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angular

I have a Card which has many Hashtags.

Array of items from multiple select html tag is not accepted by Ruby on Rails controller.

Ruby on Rails Controller has the following:

```
def card_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:name, hashtag_ids: [])
end
```

In Angular 2:

```
// card-detail.component
export interface Card {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 hashtag_ids: Array<any>;
}

export class CardDetailComponent implements OnInit, CanDeactivate {
  public card: Card;
  hashtag_ids: Array<any> = [];
  form;

  constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder
  ){
    this.form = fb.group({
      "title": ['', Validators.required],
      "hashtags": ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  save() {
    this.card.hashtags.forEach(hashtag => {
      this.hashtag_ids.push(hashtag.id);
    });
    this._service.update(this.card.id, this.card.title, this.datetime, this.hashtag_ids).subscribe(
      err => {
        return this._dialog.showError("Error. Please see log for details.");
      },
      () => {
        this._dialog.showSuccess("Item updated successfuly.");
      }
    );
  }

// card.service.component
 update (id: number, name: string, expiration_date: string, hashtag_ids: any) : Observable<Card>  {

    let body = JSON.stringify({ name, expiration_date, hashtag_ids });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.patch(this._editCardUrl + id, body, options)
                    .map(res => res.json());
  }

// card-detail.html
  <select ngControl="hashtags" [(ngModel)]="card.hashtag_ids" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="#hashtag of card.hashtags" [value]="hashtag.id" selected>{{hashtag.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="f.form.controls.hashtags.touched && !f.form.controls.hashtags.valid">Hashtag is required</div>
```

Here is what is passed to controller:

`Parameters: {"name"=>"Card 11", "hashtag_ids"=>[2, 1], "id"=>"1", "card"=>{"name"=>"Card 11"}}`

As you see, hashtag_ids are not passed as part of Card object.
Any ideas why and how to fix it?

thanks for help!

Comment: Could you give the content of the request sent through Angular2? What does "parameters" correspond to exactly (query parameters, request payload)? Thanks!

Comment: It's query parameters.

Comment: Really! Because you don't send any query parameters from your Amgular2 application ;-) Your data are sent within the payload... What do you actually want to do? A JSON payload or query parameters?

Comment: So I think that you send your request the right way in Angular2. I would see one potential problem. You could have forgotten to import the Headers class so the Content-type one wouldn't be sent... Is this header present in the request payload (see Network tab in dev tools)?

Comment: content-type is present. moreover, there are few other parameters that I pass (not shown in the example) and they work fine. the issue is only with this array...